# NXP and TMP75 I2C communication

Tags: sensor, i2c, temperature, nxp

I'm trying to read temperature from TMP75 sensor using NXP family microcontroller. I'm able receive proper temperature data, but with Send() command I'm getting errors in my handling procedure.

I've existing I2C communication that uses I2C_DMA.

```
static void DmaIrq (I2C_Type *,i2c_master_dma_handle_t *,status_t status ,void *)
{
    if (status == kStatus_Success) { transferReady = true; }
}

void Send (const uint8_t address, const uint16_t register, uint8_t * const data, const uint16_t len)
{
  i2cMasterTransfer.slaveAddress   = address;
  i2cMasterTransfer.direction      = kI2C_Write;
  i2cMasterTransfer.subaddress     = (uint32_t)register;
  i2cMasterTransfer.subaddressSize = ONE;
  i2cMasterTransfer.data           = data;
  i2cMasterTransfer.dataSize       = len;
  i2cMasterTransfer.flags          = kI2C_TransferDefaultFlag;

  I2C_MasterTransferCreateHandleDMA (i2cType, i2cMasterDmaHandle, DmaIrq, NULL, dmaHandle);
  auto status = I2C_MasterTransferDMA (i2cType, i2cMasterDmaHandle, &i2cMasterTransfer);
}

I have similar code to handle Receive() for I2C.
```

When communicating with Tmp75 sensor I run following code:

```
uint8_t register = 0x00;
uint8_t data = 0x00;
Send(deviceAddress, register, data , 1);

std::array<uint8_t, 2> data;
Receive (deviceAddress, register, data.data(), data.size());
```

My main issue is no matter if my device is even connected or I set proper address, `auto status = I2C_MasterTransferDMA` always return 0.

Moreover, my callback DmaIrq during `Send()` is called twice with status:

- 2602 - `kStatus_I2C_Nak`
- 2609 - `kStatus_I2C_UnexpectedState`

My `Receive()` seems to read data properly and status in callback is set properly to `kStatus_Success`.

Is it a problem with my I2C code or should I send different frames to Tmp75?